# Cargar varias fila de un Datagridview a textbox para poder editarlo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Aquí propongo una pregunta para ver si es posible conseguir editar 2 filas de un **DATAGRIDVIEW** (cargando ambas fila al hacer click o por via de un boton).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi imagen muestro un **DATAGRIDVIEW** que contiene 3 columnas con datos, y en la parte superior contengo 8 **TEXTBOX**.
Imaginemos que vendo jugo y ese jugo lleva 2 ingrediente y quiero obtener datos independientes de ellos.
En la celda del ID tengo 2 números de ID (1 y 2), podría por los números de ID conseguir cargar ambas filas a la vez en los **TEXTBOX** y posteriormente poder editar esos datos

Comment: Ese enfoque no creo que sea correcto, y si tuvieras 5, 10, etc ingredientes cuantos textbox vas a poner entonces, en este caso o editas dentro del mismo datagridview o una sola fila a la vez

Comment: Hola @Japv gracias por tu planteamiento, pero no le veo nada de malo que tenga 15 a 20 ingredientes. Hice un planteamiento a mi problema de esa manera para poder explicarme mejor.

Comment: Si tiene de 15 a 20 ingredientes  vas a tener un textbox por cada ingrediente, es decir tendrias 15 o 20 textbox uno al lado del otro, lo que es ineficiente, pero ademas la cantidad de ingredientes es variable segun el platillo, como vas a saber la cantidad de textbox a mostrar?

Comment: Osea no es lo que voy hacer en realidad, en verdad lo que quiero saber si hay pa posibilidad de editar varias fila a partir de un ID o algún nombre. Ya estoy creando una aplicación que necesito hacer algo así ya que debo cargar 3 filas al mismo tiempo al datagridview.